# Is it possible to grab data from one column given that another column is empty in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I am making therapy notes in google sheets, I have provided my sheet for reference. I am trying to make it so that it automatically inputs what we worked on on a certain date for that dates medicaid note (cell L7). As of right now I have it so that it grabs the information for the column that the date is on, however if the client worked on multiple targets in one session I want it to input all of the targets for that day into the medicaid note as well as the accuracy, but stop whenever a new date is put in the A column, as that would be the start of the next session. I hope this makes sense. Thank you for your help!
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sDdziCrg2W9uvyd5nRrjhBnhLeTiu8PdNzyJuW-thm4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Your file isn't accessible. Please change the share permission.

Comment: @Daniele just updated it!

Comment: @BlindSpots I just added into the sheet in example data and a column with what my desired medicaid note would look like with it all autofilled. I hope this is helpful to get across what I want to get done

Answer (score 0):

So you want to autocomplete ColL but only when the date is inserted?

Maybe you can set work with all the rows, but only put the introduction of the patient info in the first one. For example:

Row 1: "Patient ccc worked this day with this target with this disposition and this accuracy"

Row 2: "He also worked with this other target with this disposition and this accuracy"

Row 3: "he also worked..."

This way if you need to insert this information maybe in another software, perhaps from your institution, you can copy the three rows and they'll be inserted as three coherent paragraphs

If this is useful you can set an if formula, even with an array formula that concatenates these options depending on it there is data or not in the date column. Let me know, and I can go a little further

Comment: Correct, so the goal is to write a medicaid note for every date that the client is worked with. I want it to autofill their disposition, what was targeted and with what accuracy. I have that dont right now if they only targeted one thing, however if in a session we targeted more than 1 target I want it to add that target and with what accuracy into the medicaid note as well.

Comment: I get it, but can it be done in each row of L but sequentially as I described earlier??

Comment: I was able to do this, this is what my function looks like: =IF(D7:D100<>"", IF(A1:A102<>"", A1 & " had a " & C7:C100 & " disposition and worked on " & D7:D100 & " with " & round(MULTIPLY(H7:H100, 100)) & "% accuracy.", A1 & " also worked on " & D7:D100 & " with " & ROUND(MULTIPLY(H7:H100, 100)) & "% accuracy."), ""). The only problem with this is that it pastes it with spaces inbetween the sentences like this: "John had a happy disposition and worked on /k/ in the initial position with 83% accuracy.


John also worked on /k/in the final position with 77% accuracy." not the end of the world

Comment: Ah, it doesn't paste the spaces between the sentences on here, but on the software I insert medicaid notes it pastes the spaces

Comment: @Drew you should post your answer if it is a good solution so others can benefit.  You are allowed to answer your own question.  Comments are not for answers.